# Flutter: printing, path_provider and cloud_firestore packages make APK build fail

Tags: android, flutter, apk, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to build the APK for my flutter app, but I keep getting these warnings. All the packages are updated to their latest version.

```
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cloud_firestore-2.5.4\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\streamhandler\TransactionStreamHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider-2.0.6\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\pathprovider\PathProviderPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\printing-5.6.0\android\src\main\java\net\nfet\flutter\printing\PrintingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.       
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

This is my `build.gradle`. I've tried to build with `compileSdkVersion 30` but that makes the build fail

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.gbergatto.door_app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

When I run the app in the emulator to develop it, it works. But when I try to install the APK on my phone it doesn't open. I've tried both release and debug APKs.